# how to put comma in every 3 digit for a number

Tags: php

I want to put comma in every 3 digit for a number, for example.

```
$number = 1234567;
// should print 1,234,567
```

how can I do this?

**update: please see this code**

```
<?php
/**
 * Get Popularity Text of a Domain via Alexa XML Data
 *
 * @return string|FALSE text or FALSE on error
 */
function alexa_get_rank($domain)
{
    $alexa = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=%s";
    $request_url =  sprintf($alexa, urlencode($domain));


    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    if (!$xml) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $nodeAttributes = $xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes();
    $text = (int) $nodeAttributes['TEXT'];

    $num = number_format($text);

    return $num;
}
```

**in this return only 3 digit.**

Comment: A simple search would have gave you this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424120/format-a-number-with-grouped-thousands)

Comment: I have searched about this but my questionis a little deffrent, see my updated question please

Answer (score 19):

Use

```
echo number_format('1234567');
```

[PHP Manual : number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: hello, It return 1. that's all

Comment: @KhaledBawazir please be clear what you are saying. here is working example: http://codepad.org/Hi3UibfZ

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$number = 1234567;
echo number_format($number);
```

Use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) as ref.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = 123456789;
$number = number_format($number);
echo $number;
```

Answer (score 1):

See [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
<?php
echo number_format(1234567890); //1,234,567,890
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $num = 1234567.65;
 $num = number_format($num);
 echo $num; // $num = 1,234,568
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$number = 1234567;
echo number_format($number); // this returns : 1,234,567
?>
```

Learn more about [number_format();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = 1234.56;

//english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);// 1,235


// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');// 1 234,56


//----------------------------------------------


$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');// 1234.57
```

Check out [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) at [php.net](http://php.net) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To format numbers, one can use `number_format`

Try this code:

```
$number=1234567;  
$number_format=number_format($number,0,".",","); // return 1,234,567
```