# Number formating - always 2 to 4 decimals after decimal separator and with thousand separator

Tags: php

I have number:

1. 2000
2. 100
3. 0.1
4. 0.15
5. 0.1555

But I need show these number in this format:

1. 2,000.00
2. 100.00
3. 0.10
4. 0.15
5. 0.1555

I will never have more than 4 decimals after decimal separator.
If after decimal separator are only null, I need to display 2 nulls (3. example above).

How I can format these numbers to get required format?
Thank you!

**EDIT**: I can't use just `number_format` function, because with this function I can only set how many decimals will be after decimal separator, but as I wrote above - sometimes there will be 2, sometimes 4. So, if my number is `2000.0001` and I set this `number_format(2000.0001, 4)` output will be `2000.0001`, but other number like `0.1` will output `0.1000`, but I need it with `0.10` format.

Comment: Use `number_format` to get 4 digits, then remove any zeroes at the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format a number with grouped thousands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424120/format-a-number-with-grouped-thousands)

Comment: @ledesma That doesn't show how to get a variable number of digits after the decimal.

Comment: it gives you a [link](http://us.php.net/number_format) which explains how to do it.

Comment: @ledesma There's nothing in `number_format` that does this by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `number_format` to add the commas and get 4 digits after the decimal. Then use a regular expression to remove up to 2 trailing zeroes.

```
$formatted = preg_replace('/0{1,2}$/', '', number_format($input, 4));
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/M8tfEl)